# real time audio recording and sending

Tags: android

I'm trying to capture audio from a microphone and no matter what buffer 
size (`bufferSizeInBytes`) I set at construct time of `AudioRecord`, when 
I do a `AudioRecord.read` I always get `8192` bytes of audio data (128 
ms). I would like the `AudioRecord.read` be able to read `40ms` of data 
(`2560 bytes`). The only working sample code that I can find is Sipdroid 
([`RtpStreamSender.java`](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/media/RtpStreamSender.java%29)) which I haven't tried.
 Here's the relevant piece of my code:

```
public void run()
{ 
running = true; 
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URG ENT_AUDIO); 
try { 
     frameSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(samplingRate, 
              AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT); 
     Log.i(TAG, "trying to capture " + String.format("%d", frameSize) + " bytes"); 
     record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, samplingRate, 
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, frameSize);
     record.startRecording(); 
     byte[] buffer = new byte[frameSize]; 
     while (running)
     { 
        record.read(buffer, 0, frameSize); 
        Log.i(TAG, "Captured " + String.format("%d", frameSize) + " bytes of audio"); 
     } 
     record.stop(); 
     record.release(); 
 } catch (Throwable t) { 
 Log.e(TAG, "Failed to capture audio"); 
   } 
 }
```

My questions/comments are:

1. Is this a limitation of AudioRecord class and/or the particular 
   device ?
2. I don't see a method to query the supported sampling rate (steps of 
   bufferSizeInBytes) a given device can do. It would be nice if there's 
   one.
3. Can we use AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener and how?
4. In above code encoding pcm in 8 bit is not working. why?
   if anyone tried sipdroid code, help me.
   Thanks in advance,

Comment: From what I can tell, this is a limitation of the AudioRecord API and devices :).  The minimum buffer size seems to vary from device to device.